# Bootstrap 4 - Full Width Nav with Outermost Links Touching Container Edges

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a full-width nav bar with Bootstrap 4 and have the left and right most links touch the edge of the container (see the nav on Etsy.com for an example of what I'm trying to achieve):

[image: Etsy]

I've tried to use `text-left` on each nav link, but the right-most link isn't aligned properly.

Here is the CodePly I'm using:
https://www.codeply.com/go/I9X4D7HpZ2

[image: My Nav]

How do I get the nav to be full width, with the left and right most links touching the edges?
Thanks

Current Code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light pl-2 pt-0 pb-2 border-bottom">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark mr-4 text-left" href="#">Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark mr-4 text-left" href="#">Link 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark mr-4 text-left" href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark mr-4 text-left" href="#">Link 4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark mr-4 text-left" href="#">Link 5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark text-left" href="#">Link 6</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You have to override default bootstrap styles and there are also some classes that are causing some problems (like text-left). Try this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div>

                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white flex-row">
                    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="/"><span style="color:#0099ff">MyBrand</span></a>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-lg-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </nav>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light pl-2 pt-0 pb-2 border-bottom">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <li class="nav-item flex-grow-0">
                                    <a class="nav-link d-inline-block text-dark text-center" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item flex-grow-0">
                                    <a class="nav-link d-inline-block text-dark text-center" href="#">Link 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item flex-grow-0">
                                    <a class="nav-link d-inline-block text-dark text-center" href="#">Link 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item flex-grow-0">
                                    <a class="nav-link d-inline-block text-dark text-center" href="#">Link 4</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item flex-grow-0">
                                    <a class="nav-link d-inline-block text-dark text-center" href="#">Link 5</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item flex-grow-0">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark text-center" href="#">Link 6</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </header>
    </div>
```